# NullPointerException when removing first node of a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a method that removes any value in a linked list that is larger than the input max. I have written out the code and it works for every case except when the first node is greater than the input max value, which then produces a NullPointerException. I was hoping that someone could help me out.

Here is the code I have so far:

```java
public static void removeValuesLargerThanMax(SinglyLinkedList list, int max){
    Node cur = list.head;
    Node prev = null;

    while(cur != null){
        if(cur.data > max){
            prev.next = cur.next;
            cur = cur.next;
            continue;
        }
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you traverse the linked list, you are keeping track of `prev`, I'm assuming as the previous element in the linked list as you traverse it. However, remember that the first element of a (non-circular) linked list **does not** have a previous element.

In this case, when you are trying to remove the first element of the linked list, the following code executes:

```
prev.next = cur.next;
cur = cur.next;
```

However, the value of `prev` has not changed since it was initialized to `null`. Then, this would cause a `NullPointerException`.

Simply check if `prev` is `null` before attempting to update it. You could do something like this (also updating the head pointer):

```
if(cur.data > max){
    if(prev != null) prev.next = cur.next;
    else list.head = cur.next;
    cur = cur.next;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: better also change the head pointer if removing the first element (an `else` is missing in proposed solution, `cur.next` *must* be saved somewhere)

Comment: right, of course. let me add it.

Answer (score 0):

In this line
prev.next = cur.next;
when first node is greater than max input then prev value is null. That's why you're getting the error.